# A decent use-case for static property

Tags: php, static

I'm currently writing a REST-tool that connects to a third-party server (duh). They offer a fairly large (if not too large) API in a single wsdl file, as well as separate wsdl's for each specific part of data you want to work on. 
When writing my code, I created an abstract `Api` class, and a number of child classes, one for each subset of the API.

Since all requests are available through a single, "master-api", there is only 1 user-password required to connect, so I've created the `getClient` and `setClient` methods in the abstract class.
Since it's not unlikely form me to be working with two, or three of these API-classes, I decided to create a private static property in the abstract class. This is to avoid excessive internal method calls, brought along by lazy-loading.
Is this a valid use-case for the `static` keyword? It's the only time I'm using `static` in my entire code, and I have this acquired repulsion for using it.

Anyway, here's some (grossly oversimplified) version of my code:

```
namespace MyLib;
use Tool\Application,
    Tool\Command;//it's a CLI tool
use MyLib\Soap\Client;
use \Zend_Config;//can't help but liking the old Zend_Config

absctract class Api
{
    //all properties have a getter, which lazy-loads the correct object, where possible
    //can be injected through constructor, setter or via $this->command
    private $app = null;
    //inject via setter, get from application or command
    private $config = null;
    //inject via setter or child constructor
    private $command = null;
    /* This is the one */
    private static $login;

    public function __construct(Application $app = null)
    {
        $this->setApplication($app);
        if (!is_callable(array($this, 'init')))
        {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Impossible, yet somehow '.get_class($this).'::init() cannot be called');
        }
        return $this->init();
    }

    abstract protected functoin init();

    final private function getLogin()
    {
        if (self::$login === null)
        {
            $config = $this->getConfig();
            $this->setLogin(array(
                array(
                    'login'   => $config->api->login,
                    'pwd'     => $config->api->pwd
                )
            );
        }
        return self::$login;
    }

    final private function setLogin(array $login)
    {
        if (count(array_filter($login) === 2)
        {
            self::$login = $login;
        }
        return $this;
    }

    protected fucntion getClient()
    {
        if ($this->client === null)
        {
            $wsdl = $this->getConfig();
            $wsdl->api->{$this->getName()}->wsdl;
            $this->setClient(
                new Client(
                    $wsdl,
                    $this->getLogin()
                )
            );
        }
        return $this->client;
    }

    public fucntion setClient(Client $client = null)
    {
        if ($this->client)
        {
            $this->client->disconnect();
        }
        $this->client = $client;
        return $this;
    }

    protected function getConfig()
    {
        if ($this->config === null)
        {//getApplication falls back to $this->getCommand()->getApplication()
            $this->setConfig(
                $this->getApplication()->getConfig()
            );
        }
        return $this->config;
    }

    public function setConfig(Zend_Config $config = null)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

As for the child classes, they look something like this:

```
namespace MyLib\Apis;
use MyLib\Api;
use MyLib\Data\Models\Model;

class Foo extends Api
{
    public function __construct($mixed = null)
    {
        if ($mixed instanceof Command)
        {
            $this->setCommand($mixed);
        }
        parent::__construct($mixed instanceof Application ? $mixed : null);
    }

    protected function init()
    {
        $this->setName('foo');//<-- init is a tad more complicated, but not relevant here
    }

    public function doRequest(Model $data = null)
    {
        $client = $this->getClient();
        //worst case here:
        // parent::getClient getConfig -> getApplication -> getCommand {->setApplication(command->getApplication())}->getConfig <== setConfig of $this here
        return $client->getSomething(
            array(
                'param'  => $data->foobar
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Every `getClient` *can* result in as much as 12 method calls. By creating a static array containing the login data, I can make sure that the maximum number of calls is 12 once, and then, a maximum of 9 calls applies to all instances.
If this is indeed a good use case for statics, I'm thinking of creating a second static (though my heart really is bleeding just thinking about it) that'll hold the `Application` instance, which, in order for an application to use my lib, it needs to hold the config file, which is what I'm after.

If I create those two statics, the theoretical maximum of 12 method calls remains, but after the full 12 calls have been made once, This can be reduced to only 4 when I'm getting the config, 6 upon calling `getClient` the first time. 
Half of the calls I'm currently making, which, could make a difference IMO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it a "good" use-case? Not in my opinion. Is it "decent"? I think it is decent enough to get the job done if that is how you want to do it. The beauty of it is, anything is "decent" enough if it works for you, and things could always be "better". I find that I mostly use statics for Singletons and simple utility functions -- otherwise, the benefits rarely outweigh the drawbacks.

Personally, I would not go this route; even though it may make things easier to write initially, it would also make it hard to do any type of unit testing.

It seems like you may also be assuming that no one, ever, for any reason, may have more than one set of login details that they would like to use at the same time. While that might be true, I wouldn't want to make that assumption.

If it were me, I would approach this like any other adapter -- create independent classes with single responsibilities and use dependency injection for configuration/etc. Finally, I would create a facade which implements those responsibilities, and handles the dependencies, in order to provide an "easy to use" interface without taking away the user's ability to do things at a lower level.

To me, this would give you the most testability and maintainability, without placing constraints on the how someone else could use the code (and still provide an easy interface as well).

Of course, that is just my opinion.

Comment: Well, the use of a static `$login` might indeed prove to be a drawback in time, but a static `$app`? These are _"services"_ or _"helpers"_, that the application will be using in order for it to get data via the API. The Application cannot run without having the `$config` set, and I can inject the application instance once, set it statically and use it everywhere, can't I. That way, if multiple logins come into play, there still is no issue

Comment: PS: You talk about dependency injection, but at the same time admit to using Singletons in PHP... Sorry if I'm being obtuse here, but that doesn't make sense IMO

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem - To your first comment -- yes and no, in my opinion. While you "can" inject everything into a single container which everything references, this leaves no flexibility without complicating your classes. Take, for example, a second configuration or login -- this would require you to now add special code to your classes for determining which "set" of information to use. It would be better to allow this information to be passed, which abstracts away the environmental "choices" and allows the classes to focus only on accomplishing their tasks. (continued...)

Comment: I know you're probably typing the rest of your reply ATM, but I should point out that the config object is structured in such a way that each component has only accesses a subset of the entire config, based on the abstract class (using its namespace, instance name and task: `app.helpers.db.user_db.login="userlogin"` and so on) so adding new login data for a specific class is doddle, the constructor and init functions take care of that for me

Comment: To me, there is also nothing wrong with having a `$app` to accomplish bootstrapping and create a facade for your underlying structures. The difference is in passing the `$app` to your individual components and having them make their own choices as to what to do with this larger structure, rather than limiting their responsibilities to solely accomplishing the tasks for which they are intended. Now -- maybe you are using additional patterns within your `$app` which limit this, but I'm just giving my opinion on why I wouldn't approach it that way.

Comment: Well, you've got a point there. I wasn't all too clear about this, but the way the `$app` instance is passed about is indeed restricted. I'm using a double service layer. Whereas one service links the application to the business logic, the other is a sort-of service locator that manages the communication between the actual service (and application) and the various helpers and mappers. Based on what part of the application, I pre-set a subset of the config on the instance, prior to setting the app reference, for example. In some cases I can't and for those cases, I'd use that static app ref.

Comment: To your 2nd comment, Singletons and dependency injection are not mutually exclusive, in my opinion, even though others may disagree. You can't argue with someone who thinks THEIR method of using a hammer is the only way one should EVER drive a nail. To me, overuse, misuse and poor implementation doesn't make a pattern bad, it makes the "bad" implementations bad. While I agree that the need for Singletons is rare and that there are always ways to "get around" the use of the Singleton Pattern, that doesn't mean the alternative is always the best solution. Just my 2 cents, my friend.

Comment: Your comment, 2nd above, sounds like a lot of complication, which may just be terminology, but it sounds like there is a significant amount of intermingling between your individual classes, the overarching application, configuration and individual service layers/components/helpers/etc. Like I said, "sounds" that way -- it may not be. For me, if I have more than a couple dependencies on other classes, need objects within other objects within other objects, or need more than a couple words to explain other classes in order to explain what my class does, I look at whether I need to refactor.